# Responsive design doesn't work after redirecting URL?

Tags: html, url, redirect

This is the original URL: http://ugweb.cas.mcmaster.ca/~maliksa4

This is the URL that's redirecting to it: http://saimmalik.xyz

For some reason, the responsiveness of the website doesn't work when the website is accessed through the redirecting URL on a mobile device.

(Also, the favicon of the original site doesn't show if it's accessed through the redirecting URL)

Any ideas on how I could fix this?

Answer (score 1):

you need to add view port meta tag in your new page.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably happening because you are using masking redirection, therefore you might be able to fix this by changing your redirection type to redirect only. Otherwise you will have to stick with solution proposed by @YoYo but not all providers will let you modify your masking redirection with such level of detail.